# search blog posts by author first name and or last name

Tags: posts, wp-query, rest-api

I am trying to create and endpoint where blog posts can be searched by author first name and/or last name. I was trying to do this with WP_Query but it uses the user nice name for the search which is not working. Is there a way to do this using a built in query or do I need to do a custom SQL query?

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'blog-posts/v1', 'blog-by-author', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'get_posts_by_author',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
  ) );
} );

function get_posts_by_author(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $data = $request->get_params();
    $author_name = $data['author_name'];
    
   // this uses nice name, not first/last name
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'author_name' => $author_name ) );
    
    return print_r($query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you set `author_name`, `WP_Query` will use [`get_user_by( 'slug', <author name> )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) to find a user with the specified "nice name" (`user_nicename`) value, and if found, then `WP_Query` sets the `author` arg to the found user's ID.

Therefore you can follow the same approach, but you would use [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) to find users having the specified first and/or last name *and use the `author` (or `author__in`) arg with `WP_Query`*. E.g.

```php
$users = get_users( array(
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $request['author_name'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $request['author_name'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    'fields'      => 'ID',
) );

if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => $users[0] ) );
    // or to include all found users..
//  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => $users ) );

    // ... your code.
}
```

### Additional Notes

- You don't have to do the `$data = $request->get_params();` because you could just access parameters via direct array access on the `WP_REST_Request` object, e.g. `$request['author_name']` like in my example above.
- You should register `author_name` using [`args` in the third parameter for `register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments), or at least, check that it's not empty before calling `get_users()`.
- I know the `print_r()` in your code is just for testing, but the function will actually echo the output unless if the second parameter is set to `true`..

Comment: This is really excellent, thanks so much. Just a quick question.. The featured image and slug are not in the response. If I wanted to add these, could I do it inside of this code or do I need to use `register_rest_field` ?

Comment: Yes, you could. E.g. `$data = array(); foreach ( $query->posts as $p ) { $item = array(); $item['id'] = $p->ID; $item['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $p ); $data[] = $item; } return $data;`

Comment: Thanks again, I will certainly try that out!